# Building a class name using Data in a haml/ruby project

Tags: ruby, haml

I currently have some haml code which reads as

```
%span.flagb.flag-gb
```

this builds me a nice span which the classes:
flagB
flag-gb

(which puts a nice sprite on the page of the gb (great britian) flag

Now I dont want to hard code the gb I have the iso country code which I can access with a 
=code

but I am so new I dont know about the best way of replacing the "gb" with the code value

Full code below as how i have it atm

```
- TZInfo::Country.all_codes.each do |code|
  %li
    %a(href='#')
      %span.flagb.flag-gb
      =code
```

only way I have managed it so far is using pure html

`<span class='flagB flag-#{code'></span>`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.classname` syntax is just a shorthand, you can do it the long way:

```
%span{:class => "flagb flag-#{code}"}
```

See the [HAML reference on `class` and `id` attributes](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#class-and-id-attributes) for more information.

Comment: The `()` syntax also supports interpolation, e.g. `%span(class="flagb flag-#{code}")`.

Comment: @Jordan I actually didn't know about that form till I started perusing the reference just now, nice.